# SSH to EC2 instance through Gitlab CICD and run commands

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I am currently using gitlab CICD to ssh to one of our running Gitlab EC2 instance to run rake commands. I have the following code for testing purpose and It seems that while the SSH connection is established successfully, subsequent commands such as pwd and ls -l /etc/gitlab are not being executed. This issue causes the pipeline to hang without completing the execution of the desired commands.

```js
image: buildtime_base_v2:3.25.1

stages:

  - test

test:

  stage: test

  script:

    - |

      echo "$SSH_KEY_VARIABLE" > ssh_key.pem

      chmod 600 ssh_key.pem

      ssh -i "ssh_key.pem" -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no centos@<ip>

      pwd

      ls -l /etc/gitlab
```

Answer (score 2):

This YAML isn't telling SSH to run any commands remotely; it's saying "SSH to the box, and then when you're done run these other commands locally". You'll need to put the remote-system commands into  the SSH command: `ssh -i /path/to/key <other options here> user@host "pwd && ls -l /etc/gitlab/"`. This will SSH to `host` using the specified parameters; run `pwd` on `host`; and then, if `pwd` exited successfully, run `ls -l /etc/gitlab/` on `host`.

If the commands to run remotely become unwieldy, then put them in a script *on the remote host*: `ssh -i /path/to/key <other options here> user@host "/opt/deployment_script.sh"`. This will SSH to `host` using the specified parameters, and then run `/opt/deployment_script.sh` on `host`.